# file_put_contents - failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, file-io, file-permissions

I am trying to write a query to a file for debugging. The file is in `database/execute.php`. The file I want to write to is `database/queries.php`.

I am trying to use `file_put_contents('queries.txt', $query)`

But I am getting

> file_put_contents(queries.txt) [function.file-put-contents]:
>   failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied

I have the `queries.txt` file chmod'd to 777, what could the issue be?

Comment: Have you looked through the `php.ini` file for anything that might deny file access?

Comment: also make sure the directory is chmod'd right

Comment: also try using the absolute filename. It might just be that your interpretation of current folder is different from PHP's

Comment: Can you double-check that chmod status?

Comment: @Crayon Violent is correct...your PHP script running as `nobody` or `apache` does not have read access to the directory the file is in - even though its 777.

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this kind of problems : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try adjusting the directory permissions.

from a terminal, run `chmod 777 database` (from the directory that contains the database folder)

apache and nobody will have access to this directory if it is chmodd'ed correctly.

The other thing to do is echo "getcwd()". This will show you the current directory, and if this isn't '/something.../database/' then you'll need to change 'query.txt' to the full path for your server.

Comment: Isn't 777 a security risk?

Comment: I strongly suspect that not only must the target directory be writeable by the server account, but every parent directory of the target directory must allow the server account to navigate into it; I think this would be +x to the permissions.

Comment: I experimented Erhannis' theories on a new LAMP stack and the theory is right.

Comment: @Erhannis where should `+x` go? What is the complete command with `+x` added?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour I think `chmod +x /parent/directory`, for every parent directory of the target.  `chmod +x /parent/directory`, `chmod +x /parent`, etc.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this kind of problems : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: After you find out what user the file is created as, change that chmod to 700 and chown the directory to the user in question.

Answer (score 33):

You can make `Apache (www-data)`, the owner of the folder:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

that should make `file_put_contents` work now. But for more security you better also set the permissions like below:

```
find /var/www -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755 # folder
find /var/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644 # files
```

- change `/var/www` to the root folder of your php files

Comment: your find command does not work, I get `Argument list too long`

Comment: @Black guess you need to change `/var/www` to your app's directory

Comment: @Black use 'xargs' as described here https://superuser.com/a/91938/1086206

Comment: Changing the folder's owner fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

There's no need to manually write queries to a file like this. MySQL has logging support built in, you just need to enable it within your dev environment.

Take a look at [the documentation for the 'general query log'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html).

Answer (score 5):

Gathering info from this link [stackoverflow-image save doesn't work with chmod 777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285486/image-save-doesnt-work-with-chmod-755-but-does-with-777-what-should-i-do) and from user azerafati and Loek Bergman:

If you were to look under the /etc/apache/envvars file, you will see something like:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

Apache is run under the username 'www-data'

'0755' means the file owner can read/write/execute but group and other users cannot write. so in ur terminal, cd to the folder containing your 'images' folder. then type:

```
find images -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
find images -type f -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data images
```

You must change permissions first before changing owner.
Enter your password when prompted. This will make 'www-data' owner of the images folder.

Your upload should now work.

Answer (score 4):

I know that it is a very old question, but I wanted to add the good solution with some in depth explanation. You will have to execute two statements on Ubuntu like systems and then it works like a charm.

Permissions in Linux can be represented with three digits. The first digit defines the permission of the owner of the files. The second digit the permissions of a specific group of users. The third digit defines the permissions for all users who are not the owner nor member of the group.

The webserver is supposed to execute with an id that is a member of the group. The webserver should never run with the same id as the owner of the files and directories. In Ubuntu runs apache under the id www-data. That id should be a member of the group for whom the permissions are specified.

To give the directory in which you want to change the content of files the proper rights, execute the statement:

```
find %DIR% -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
```

.That would imply in the question of the OP that the permissions for the directory %ROOT%/database should be changed accordingly. It is therefor important not to have files within that directory that should never get changed, or removed. It is therefor best practice to create a separate directory for files whose content must be changed.

Reading permissions (4) for a directory means being able to collect all files and directories with their metadata within a directory. Write permissions (2) gives the permission to change the content of the directory. Implying adding and removing files, changing permissions etc.. Execution permission (1) means that you have the right to go into that directory. Without the latter is it impossible to go deeper into the directory. The webserver needs read, write and execute permissions when the content of a file should be changed. Therefor needs the group the digit 7.

The second statement is in the question of the OP:

```
find %DOCUMENT_ROOT%/database -type f -exec chmod 760 {} \;
```

Being able to read and write a document is required, but it is not required to execute the file. The 7 is given to the owner of the files, the 6 to the group. The webserver does not need to have the permission to execute the file in order to change its content. Those write permissions should only be given to files in that directory.

All other users should not be given any permission.

For directories that do not require to change its files are group permissions of 5 sufficient.
Documentation about permissions and some examples:

https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions

http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/

Answer (score 3):

This can be resolved in resolved with the following steps :

```
1. $ php artisan cache:clear

2. $ sudo chmod -R 777 storage

3. $ composer dump-autoload
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This worked for me. But the science behind it remains unknown

Comment: `chmod -R 777` is [always a bad idea](https://askubuntu.com/a/20110/349837)

Answer (score 2):

I use a shared Linux hosting, when my admin changed the php to 5.3 I got many errors for the "file_put_contents" code. try to test my plan:

In your host create a file like mytest.php, and put this code in and save:

```
<?php        mail('Your-EMail','Email-Title','Email-Message');        ?>
```

Open the URL "www.your-domain.com/mytest.php" one time and then check your email. You should have an email from your host with the information you entered in mytest.php, check the sender name. If it's from **Nobody** you have problem about "Permission Denied" because something not defined and if the sender name is like my id: iietj8qy@hostname5.netly.net you don't have a problem.

My admin changed the server and installed the host again I think and the problem got solved, tell your host administration what I told you and maybe they find the answer.

Comment: I'm completely lost!! What are you trying to say? If you are saying that the apache user was unable to get the hostname on the server(shared or whatever), then it's high time you reconsider your choice of a hosting service.

Answer (score 2):

If you are pulling from git from local to server, you will need to clear cache sometimes because of the view files it gets uploaded with it / or other cached files .

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Sometimes it might just to the trick if your application was working before the git pull

Comment: Yep, view:clear worked for me. Don't know why such an error would come up so often!

Answer (score 2):

this might help. It worked for me. try it in the terminal

`setenforce 0`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using Ubuntu and receiving this error when loading the page locally, but not on a web hosting service,

I just fixed this by opening up nautilus (`sudo nautilus`) and right click on the file you're trying to open, click properties > Settings > and give read write to 'everyone else'

Answer (score 1):

use this cammand to give permission for storage/framework and logs

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 storage/logs storage/framework
```

if you still have a permission error
try this to give group to write in log

```
sudo chmod g+w storage/logs
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem; my issue was selinux was set to enforcing.

I kept getting the "failed to open stream: Permission denied" error even after chmoding to 777 and making sure all parent folders had execute permissions for the apache user. Turns out my issue was that selinux was set to enforcing (I'm on centos7), this is a devbox so I turned it off.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped the virus scanner (Avast). That solved the problem! It eventually appeared that Avast had a ransomware shield blocking the write actions to the documentroot folder(s). Adding the shield exceptions for the individual programs (PHP, Tesseract) solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, I'm using Laravel, so what I just did was:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

And fixed!

Answer (score 0):

if the folder you are working on is hidden the function file_put_contents will throw permission denied error.
make sure this option is not set.
[image]

Answer (score -3):

Here the solution.
To copy an img from an URL.
this URL: `http://url/img.jpg`

```
$image_Url=file_get_contents('http://url/img.jpg');
```

create the desired path finish the name with `.jpg`

```
$file_destino_path="imagenes/my_image.jpg";

file_put_contents($file_destino_path, $image_Url)
```

Answer (score -3):

There 2 way to resolve this issues

1. use `chmod 777 path-to-your-directory`.

if it does not work then

2. simply provide the complete path of your file `query.txt`.

Comment: This is horribly insecure and extremely bad practice. It is also hard to detect and correct when developing custom applications and can be easily overlooked. Please actually figure out the right permissions.

Answer (score -12):

Furthermore, as said in `file_put_contents man page` in `php.net`, beware of naming issues.

```
file_put_contents($dir."/file.txt", "hello");
```

may not work (even though it is correct on syntax), but

```
file_put_contents("$dir/file.txt", "hello");
```

works. I experienced this on different php installed servers.

Comment: This is not correct. `$dir."/file.txt"` is functionally equivalent to `"$dir/file.txt"` in all cases, assuming `$dir` is a string. Furthermore, this behavior is not documented on php.net, as Kivanc claims.

Comment: Wont php interpret string vars values when in double quotes and not in single quotes?