# file_put_contents permission denied + livedocx

Tags: php, zend-framework, permission-denied, livedocx

I'm working with LiveDocx and zend framework to generate a word document from a template with values. This is what I do in my controller:

```
public function createwordAction(){
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    require_once 'Zend/Service/LiveDocx/MailMerge.php';

    try{
        $filename = APPLICATION_PATH . "/../public/license-agreement-template.docx";

        chmod($filename,0777);

        $mailMerge = new Zend_Service_LiveDocx_MailMerge();

        $mailMerge->setUsername('******')
                  ->setPassword('*******');

        $mailMerge->setLocalTemplate($filename);

        $mailMerge->assign('software', 'Magic Graphical Compression Suite v1.9')
        ->assign('licensee', 'Henry Döner-Meyer')
        ->assign('company',  'Co-Operation')
        ->assign('date',     'January 11, 2010')
        ->assign('time',     'January 11, 2010')
        ->assign('city',     'Berlin')
        ->assign('country',  'Germany');

        $mailMerge->createDocument();

        $document = $mailMerge->retrieveDocument('docx');

        file_put_contents('document.docx', $document);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        die ('Application error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

But I always get the error:

> Warning: file_put_contents(document.docx): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/site/application/controllers/ResultsController.php on line 313

As you can see I tried to change the file permissions with chmod but that didn't do the trick ...

I also tried to change permissions of public folder like this:

```
$path = APPLICATION_PATH . "/../public";
chmod($path,0777);
```

But same result was given ..

Answer (score 0):

You should try **`chmod 777`**

```
chmod($filename,0777);
```

Comment: Changed path to APPLICATION_PATH . "/../public"; and then changed code to "chmod($path,0777);"

Comment: Can you SFTP/FTP and try that ?

Comment: I'm working with vagrant and executed this statement: chmod -R 777 /vagrant/site/public/

Comment: @niels123, Similar thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989984/file-put-contents-saying-permission-denied

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `mod` of **directory** and **file** both like,

```
 $dir=APPLICATION_PATH . "/../public/";
 $filename = $dir."license-agreement-template.docx";
 chmod($dir,0777);
 chmod($filename,0777);
```

Also the name of **file** in which you want to **put the contents** should be the `$filename` like

```
file_put_contents($filename, $document);
```

In **place of**

```
file_put_contents('document.docx', $document);
```