# PHP is_writable() returns true but file_put_contents() returns false

Tags: php

I'm having trouble writing to a file even though `is_writable()` returns true. Of course, the file exists and is apparently readable. Here is the code:

```
$file = "data";
echo file_get_contents($file)."<br>";
echo is_writable($file) ? "is writable<br>" : "not writable<br>";
if (file_put_contents($file, "ghijkl", FILE_APPEND) === FALSE) echo "failed<br>";
echo file_get_contents($file)."<br>";
```

And here is the output:

```
abcdef
is writable
failed
abcdef
```

Comment: looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917811/file-put-contents-permission-denied

Comment: first thing that comes to my mind after reading http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php is ther row: "Safe mode limitations are not taken into account." 2nd thougt is "Other problems could by" no space left on device?

Comment: There's definitely enough space because I can type `ghijkl` into the file manually. I guess the next step is to ask my admin about permissions then?

Comment: what does exec `("ghijkl>> data");` do ? Juat as a test dont keep it there longer than you need

Answer (score 1):

So just need check free space in filesystem
in my case 
i typing in console:
df -h
Filesystem     Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/da0s1f    4.3G    4.0G    -68M   102%    /usr

free up space and function file_put_contents is working after that

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the ownership of the file? It might be the reason, try to run this code:

```
chown username:groupname your_file.txt
```

Remember to change the username:groupname. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score -1):

You have to use this:

```
$file=realpath('data');
```

Then you have to use this above `$file` in file put contents and last one try to give with file type like (filename.filetype).

```
file_put_contents($file,'fgdfgfg');
```