# Image save doesn't work with chmod 755, but does with 777. What should I do?

Tags: php, chmod

I have a website where users can crop images. I usually save cropped images under a folder with "755" chmod parameters.

However, when it is 755, it doesn't work - It works when I chmod to 777 and I believe 777 is very insecure so I don't want to use it.

What could be wrong?

Ps. The system works like this. There are some pictures in server, PHP allows user to crop those images and when they click save, it should be saved on /cropped" folder. It works with 777 but not with 755.

Comment: Do you know what file permissions mean? If not, you should find a tutorial so you know *why* it doesn't work.

Comment: 755 means root has all access and permissions on folders, hence, PHP is running on it.

Comment: you may try 775, that means, the owner and the group has write access to it, but the anyone just read/execute

Comment: Will it be safe then? 775 will probably work.

Answer (score 5):

File permissions specify what the file's owner can do, and what others can do (groups, and rest of the world). You still have to specify the correct owner.

You'll probably have to change the folder's owner to your server process' user (maybe www-data, if you're using apache). Then 755 should work.

```
chown www-data:www-data /cropped
```

**Edit:** Use `chown -R` if there are subfolders inside `/cropped` and you want to change their permissions as well.

Comment: How can I find which user does PHP run on with Plesk?

Comment: usually using FTP you can just change the chmod, and you cannot chown the folders, unless hes using a virtualization/vpc/dedicated hosting

Comment: Apache in Ubuntu has `user=www-data` and `group=www-data` _by default_, but if you're not sure, you can check this in **/etc/apache2/envvars** ([from here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1293508&p=8123364#post8123364))

Comment: @lethal-guitar thank you so much! this works perfectly!! cheers

Comment: @Aris just create a file and inside put this line of code.                                                                 <?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>

Answer (score 3):

You already got your answer from other users. So, there's no need for me to further repeat that for you here.

But, you should actually learn what 755 and 777 means rather than thinking of it as some sort of psuedo-security level setting. 777 does not instantly mean insecure. And quite frankly, I see no immediate issue with you setting your image upload folder as 777.

owner, root, php executer, etc are not equivalent, though may be the same.

These words are based in English and you should take them at english value rather than some foreign construct of programming world.

Root user is like a dictator. Whatever he says goes. There's no one who can say otherwise.

When there is an object, there's an owner user. And you set the laws as to what the owner can do: read, write or execute.
 You can also set laws to what a specific group can do.
 Lastly, you can also set laws to what everyone else can do.

Now the dictator doesn't go around doing ALL the work. The one running the PHP can be one person. And the one who owns the file can be another. They could certainly be the same person, but such definitions are not equivalent. I hope you see the difference.

Here's another analogy. Think of a private park. If you allow everyone (ie 777) to enter and play in the park, are you posing some sort of a security risk? No.
 If you have a safe, who would you allow? Just yourself (the owner), right? So, that would be like 700 in linux permissions. No one else has any permission but yourself (except the dictator, because he can come to your house, kill you and take your things if he felt like it).

Answer (score 0):

755 means the owner can read/write/execute, groups and everyone (public) can only read/execute. Check the credentials of your httpd. 777 doesn't necessarily means it's insecure, just make sure to disable parsing of PHP inside that folder using either .htaccess through `-ExecCGI` or `php_flag engine off` or even `php.ini` configuration (per folder)

You may try 775 to see if the group setting suffices

Comment: nope, usually the Apache process has his own user/group, and the `public_html` has root as owner, so Apache can't modify the files, unless you chmod it to

Comment: It means the file's owner can do this - who is not necessarily `root`.

Comment: 755 means the OWNER can read/write/execute. Members of the owner's group can read and search/execute but not write - same for others. Root (who should NEVER EVER EVER be running PHP or Apache) can always do everything unless special steps are taken.

Answer (score 0):

Your /cropped directory needs to be owned by the user who is running PHP.

This is typically www-data, but you need to check your setup.