# Tweaking PHPMyAdmin, no access to directories under web root

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, file-permissions

I am developing a small *software project management* tool. One thing this tool is supposed to do is generating setup scripts for deployment of projects on clients' hosts. For this, I need to save `CREATE`, `ALTER`, and `DROP` queries that PHPMyAdmin generates when creating/updating the DB schema for projects.

To do that, I have written a script that I `require` from within `tbl_create.php` with

```
require_once('/var/www/projects/lucy/services/db_change_logger.php');
```

The require fails with the following error message. What is wrong?

> **Fatal error**:  require_once() [function.require.html]:
>   Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/projects/lucy/services/db_change_logger.php'
>   (include_path='.') in **/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_create.php** on
>   line **225**

**Update**
Here is result of proposed probing by @mschuett:

```
majid@majid-1015PX:~$ cd /var/www/projects/lucy/services/
majid@majid-1015PX:/var/www/projects/lucy/services$ pwd
/var/www/projects/lucy/services
majid@majid-1015PX:/var/www/projects/lucy/services$ ls -la
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 2 majid majid 4096 2014-09-17 00:01 .
drwxrwxrwx 8 majid majid 4096 2014-09-16 11:02 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 majid majid  669 2014-09-17 00:01 db_change_logger.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 majid majid  531 2014-09-16 12:54 list_projects.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 majid majid    0 2014-09-16 00:57 project_def.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 majid majid 1265 2014-09-16 18:28 watchdog.php
```

Comment: This is by no means a solution but does running chmod 777 on that file and then running it again cause it to run without the fatal error? This can help determine the cause of the issue.

Comment: it looks like the user phpmyadmin is running under doesn't have permission to access that script

Comment: @mschuett I have `chmod`ed the directory, but the error occurs still.

Comment: I am a bit stumped on this one. Can you navigate to the /var/www/projects/lucy/services/ folder and run pwd and also a ls -la and add the output above?

Comment: @cmorrissey shouldn't `chmod 777 /var/www/projects/lucy/services/db_change_logger.php` fix permission?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour yes if this was just a permission issue anyone should be able to include that file from any user on your system now.

Comment: @mschuett just added the log.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour what os is your server running this on? I am going to  spin one up and try to include a file from phpmyadmin.

Comment: It's possible your `include_path` is weird... try `$path = str_replace("/", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "/var/www/projects/lucy/services/"); set_include_path($path . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path() ); require_once("db_change_logger.php");`

Comment: @mschuett this is happening on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: @dave no, even with the path added it still fails. The error message has changed now to `Fatal error:  require_once() [function.require.html]: Failed opening required 'db_change_logger.php' (include_path='/var/www/projects/lucy/services/:.') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_create.php on line 228`

Comment: @mschuett there is [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917811/file-put-contents-permission-denied#comment27129251_4917999) on a similar question which might be the root cause here too. I tried several variants with `+x` added in various places but couldn't get the syntax right. Could you say what the correct syntax is? Thanks.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour you should just be able to run chmod +x filename.php and it will be good. Let me know if that works!

Comment: @mschuett no it didn't and then I changed my approach and used curl to send the query to db_change_logger.php. Still wondering why file accsess fails though.