# file_put_contents failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions, permission-denied

I get this error while trying to do `file_put_contents()`.

Apache is working as `apache` group, started with `sudo` rights. My user is in `apache` group. All dirs and files have `755` chmod.

File exists.

Locally it works fine, on remote CentOS server not. Why? How to debug that thing?

Comment: It's dangerous to give a webserver `sudo` rights and give all files `775` access...

Comment: I think he meant he started apache with `sudo apache start` which is the correct way to do it. Apache will start its own threads from the root thread using the configured user.

Comment: @CommuSoft apache wont start if binding to port 80. Can we get back to my question?

Comment: Are you sure you're writing to directory you mean to write to? Can you read data from the same file using the same path?

Comment: Yes path is OK I doublechecked.

Comment: maybe local webserver is windows and the remote one is linux which uses different rules for paths. as i recall one uses the `\\` path's the other uses `/` paths. On linux don't start the path with a dot.. it will use the current folder and give issues.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes SELINUX will prevent writing as was my problem serving from Fedora. Run:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by changing directory permission.

Run the command like

```
chmod 777 database (the directory)
```

You can use `getcwd()"` to find the directory path.

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917811/file-put-contents-permission-denied)

Comment: This is a suggestion to bypass permissions by allowing open access to the directory. Use with caution.