# can't access to symfony installer in symfony.com

Tags: php, symfony

I'm a newcomer to Symfony and I have problem installing it . On the [Symfony website](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications) it says that I have to type:

```
 php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));"
```

it errors :

```
Warning: file_put_contents(symfony): failed to open stream: Permission denied in Command line code on line 1
```

Note: I installed composer already and I have WAMP server and I can create a folder in c directory,
and also when I typed

```
php -r "readfile('https://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

in cmd it says:

```
Access is denied
```

I surfed on stackoverflow but I couldn't find any useful answers although some topics are related to my problem!!

Comment: You can find solution here [warning-file-put-contentssymfony-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826256/warning-file-put-contentssymfony-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-in)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: file\_put\_contents(symfony): failed to open stream: Permission denied in Command line code on line 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40826256/warning-file-put-contentssymfony-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-in)

Answer (score 0):

You might be having a permissions issue on Windows.

Try starting the command prompt by right-clicking it and selecting "Run as Administrator". Also run the command from the folder that you created. For example if you created the folder `C:\bin`, run the command from that folder.

Answer (score -1):

1. download it by the URL in your navigator https://symfony.com/installer
2. put the downloaded symfony.phar in your project's folder
3. go in the folder with the console and run "php symfony.phar new yourProjectName"

Comment: How is this supposed to help OP, since that's already what he was trying to do?

Comment: Did he tried with the file directly ? No ! So he can tries with my solution what's the problem Michael ?

Comment: https://symfony.com/installer now produces a "Page not found (404 error)".