# "The stream or file "laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Tags: php, laravel-5, centos

I upload the file to my cent OS server a few days ago, it was working fine, but from today I am getting the error.

> The stream or file "/var/www/html/hasibtest/storage/logs/laravel.log"
>   could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Where My log file is with 777 permission I am also trying with 0755, 0644

can anyone tell me how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_put\_contents permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917811/file-put-contents-permission-denied)

Answer (score 59):

first try this to take ownership of the directory recursively

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache
```

Then use the following to set proper directory access

```
chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

**Never Set dircetory permissions to 777 (Unless you know what you are doing)**

Comment: for my use case, i had to replace the www-data to 'apache'

Answer (score 7):

check current user: `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>`
i'm using lampp on ubuntu, so the result is **`daemon`**

then run several command, thank @Shobi

```
sudo chown -R daemon:www-data storage
sudo chown -R daemon:www-data bootstrap/cache
```

now it works

Answer (score 5):

On Centos or Red Hat

Do this first

```
 # sestatus
```

if the status is enabled, you have to disable it

```
# setenforce Permissive
```

for me the group and user is nginx so

```
chown -R nginx:nginx storage bootstrap/cache
chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: Finally, this is the real solution, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

try changing the owner of the folder and change the permission of folders

```
sudo chown -R www-data storage/logs/
sudo chmod g+w -R storage/logs
```

now apply all the rules for child files folder logs

```
cd storage/logs
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod g+s '{}' +
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you must change both. the ownership and permission, as well as the folders in these two folders.
This should affect to all children

```
sudo chown -R apache storage
sudo chown -R apache bootstrap/cache

and

chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

you can check owner

```
ls -lr
```

That command will show you who has ownership.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

`chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t $SITE_PATH`

`chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t $SITE_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way I found to fix it:

```
php artisan storage:link
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage bootstrap/cache
```