# How do I change directory permissions for laravel logs?

Tags: laravel, directory, console, file-permissions, vps

I am looking for a more detailed answer from the following resolved issue ["The stream or file "laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178033/the-stream-or-file-laravel-log-could-not-be-opened-failed-to-open-stream-pe)

I am still new to web development and when entering the suggested command (sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage) in the terminal I get the following error: chown: invalid group: ‘root:www-data’

I have also tried (sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE) leading to my project folder but got the following error: chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:www-data’

I am doing this to fix a permissions issue:

The stream or file "/home/EXAMPLEURL/EXAMPLEURL/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied.

I have found the user and group is 'nobody' by using the following commands (find / -name httpd.conf | xargs grep -i "^user") and (find / -name httpd.conf | xargs grep -i "^group").

In the terminal I have tried the following command (sudo chown -R nobody:nobody /home/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE/storage) in the storage folder, the level above it and the level above that. The terminal returns no error but the permissions error still shows on the live website

Thank you!

Comment: What OS are you running on your server (with version)?

Comment: CENTOS 7.9 kvm v98.0.9

Comment: Are you using apache or nginx?

Comment: I am using Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, courtesy of a kind soul named Rashedul.

The reason the above solutions didn't work was that previously the owner was nobody. Changing the owner to root allowed the change to take effect

sudo chgrp -R $USER Storage_path

Answer (score 1):

Run this below command in your server/terminal

```
chmod -R 775 storage
```

It changes read/write permission for the storage folder.

Comment: I entered the command (chmod -R 775 storage) which returned a no directory error. I then replaced storage with /home/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE which returned no error but made no change. I then also tried /home/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE/storage/logs which again returned no error but no change.

Comment: You have to be in exact storage path to run that command. For eg-  if the storage path is - var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/storage, then you have to run that command on this path - var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs

Comment: Thank you for the further help! So I went directly to the storage path (/home/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE) and ran the command (chmod -R 775 /home/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE/). This made no changes so I went one level above and tried the same command as well as (chmod -R 775 /home/EXAMPLE/). Still no changes.

Comment: Try to run this command before running that above command 
chown -R username:psacln storage

- in the above "username" is your server login username

Comment: Error: chown: invalid group: ‘USERNAME:psacln’

Comment: Check your groups in root, then run that command.

Comment: First command (groups root) returned: root : root
Second command (chown -R root:root /home/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE) returned no error.
Third command (sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE) returned: chown: invalid user: ‘www-data:www-data’

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Debian/Ubuntu, CentOS doesn't use `www-data`.

I'm pretty sure that the user and group is `apache` in your case. So, something like the following should do the trick:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /home/EXAMPLEURL/EXAMPLEURL/storage
```

Comment: I have found the user and group is 'nobody' by using the following commands (find / -name httpd.conf | xargs grep -i "^user") and (find / -name httpd.conf | xargs grep -i "^group"). I have tried the command you suggested while in the storage directory and the level above it (sudo chown -R nobody:nobody /home/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE/storage).   No errors but still the same permission denied error