# file_put_contents doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php

```
<?php

file_put_contents('demo.txt', "You can put\rAny text here");
```

doesn't create demo.txt file when executing the PHP file from a browser.  virtual server on VMware.  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your log, is there any error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900719/file-put-contents-not-creating-txt-file

Comment: almost always this turns out to be a permission issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a permission issue. Give 777 permission to your folder where you are trying to create a file

```
chmod 777 foldername.
```

However 777 may not be secure as experts say.But it can help you at the moment.

Comment: thanks guys; referenced link explains how to 'setenforce 0' and that changed the permissions to allow file writes and creation.  you guys are so helpful!

Comment: Can you please accept and vote my answer if it works for you.

Comment: how to do that, Sundar?  you were helpful as well.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work check this.

Comment: Did you get it @user10179042