# How to save a .txt file in a directory

Tags: php

I would like to understand how to save my output text file to a directory called feeds.

```
file_put_contents(date('Y-m-d_His') . './/feeds//.archive.txt', $output);
file_put_contents(date('Y-m-d_His') . '.\feeds\.archive.txt', $output);
```

There are no errors just don't understand how to tell the output file to save to a directory called feeds.

Comment: possible duplicate of permission issue please refer this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577149/php-file-put-contents-function-not-working]

Comment: All that is good I'm afraid.

Comment: One more thing why there is a `date('Y-m-d_His')` in the first `parameter` it must be static file path with name

Comment: you can see here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265274/php-create-and-save-a-txt-file-to-root-directory

Answer (score 0):

Remove `date('Y-m-d_His')` from `filepath`

```
file_put_contents('feeds/archive.txt', $output);
```

OR If you want to join date_time with file name then

```
file_put_contents('feeds/archive'.date('Y-m-d_His').'.txt', $output);
```

Keep in mind, this file name is unique now so whenever you want to get/read this file, you need to give same file name to read it

Comment: Can I still join the date to the file name this way?

Comment: yes, you can concate date_time in file name if you want like `'feeds/archive'.date('Y-m-d_His')`

Comment: Ok I have this but somehow missing the .txt extension. file_put_contents('feeds/feed'. '-'. date('Y-m-d_His').txt, $output);

Comment: Thank you this helps get everything into the same place. What I would be doing now is reading the files that are placed in the feeds folder and building one txt file for reading (done that). While this is not a great option as it grows, I need to figure out a way to perhaps only show a little data at a time. I was thinking of rather than combining all the txt into one just read what is there in "feeds" in blocks of 20 perhaps based on news date range?

Answer (score 0):

In its most basic form, **file_put_contents takes the following parameters**:

```php
file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data )
```

The call you are making is interpreting the date as a path, `'.//feeds//.archive.txt'` as the data to write, and `$output` as a [context resource](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php).

Answer (score 0):

you can create file in the same directory.

```
$date_to_save= date('Y-m-d_His');
$fileOpen = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/archive.txt","wb");
fwrite($fileOpen ,$date_to_save);<--writes
fclose($fileOpen );<---close
```

Answer (score 0):

ob_start();
<--data to capture here-->

$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();

file_put_contents('feeds/stream'. '-' .date('Y-m-d_His').'.txt', $output);

The final result - thank you