# File Permissions and CHMOD: How to set 777 in PHP upon file creation?

Tags: php, file, file-permissions, chmod

A question about file permissions when saving a file that when non existent, is created initially as new file.

Now, this all goes well, and the saved file appear to have mode `644`.

What to I have to change here, in order to make the files save as mode `777`?

```
/* write to file */

   self::writeFileContent($path, $value);

/* Write content to file
* @param string $file   Save content to which file
* @param string $content    String that needs to be written to the file
* @return bool
*/

private function writeFileContent($file, $content){
    $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Note that 0777 mode is **dangerous**.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338641/in-a-php-apache-linux-context-why-exactly-is-chmod-777-dangerous

Comment: @Phoenix thanks.  I guese 0766 will suffice (need to allow for all writing permissions). is that better?

Comment: 0766 is better; that will prevent arbitrary code execution.  Does the file need to be **world** writable, or will it suffice if only e.g., Apache can write to it?  Do you have a set of applications that need to be able to write these files?  What if you made them run as the same group and set 0764 mode instead?

Comment: not really, it's the write bit that's dangerous, not the execute :-) I would ask _why_ you think it has to be world-writable.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

PHP has a built in function called `bool chmod(string $filename, int $mode )`

http://php.net/function.chmod

```
private function writeFileContent($file, $content){
    $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
    chmod($file, 0777);  //changed to add the zero
    return true;
}
```

Comment: _Don't_ use 777, it's a _decimal_ number and nothing like what you want :-)

Comment: Is it a security risk? If file permission is 777, then attacker can use "PUT" method to upload a file into the system? Am I wrong? According to your answer, I will use your solution.

Comment: @Hasan presumably there would be some sort of Auth system in place to validate the user making the request has the necessarily permissions to execute a script with such privileges.  That said, it is certainly worth noting the principle of least privilege in all cases of software development, but technically not what the OP was asking for here :).  In addition, I don't think the method factors in at all here.  In theory a GET request to a script could trigger something like this, if that was the design.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to manually set the desired permissions with [`chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/function.chmod.php):

```
private function writeFileContent($file, $content){
    $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);

    // Set perms with chmod()
    chmod($file, 0777);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: See my comment to thescientist - the correct mask is **0777** not 777.

Comment: @paxdiablo Change made. I spend all day on the unix command line and get used to leaving off the special bits.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the permissions of an existing file, use [chmod](http://php.net/function.chmod) (change mode):

```
$itWorked = chmod ("/yourdir/yourfile", 0777);
```

If you want all new files to have certain permissions, you need to look into setting your `umode`. This is a process setting that applies a default modification to standard modes.

It is a subtractive one. By that, I mean a `umode` of `022` will give you a default permission of `755` (`777 - 022 = 755`).

But you should think *very* carefully about *both* these options. Files created with that mode will be totally unprotected from changes.