# file_put_contents not overwriting the file?

Tags: php

I'm building a game with a maze-type interface with locking and unlocking doors. I have a JSON file that keeps track of the doors that are locked, but I'm having trouble rewriting it when a new door is locked. I'm trying to write a function in PHP to do this, and this is what I have so far:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('info.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString,true);
$data["doors"][0]["right"] = true;
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
var_dump($newJsonString);

file_put_contents('info.json', $newJsonString);
```

The `var_dump` is producing the right data, but `file_put_contents` isn't actually changing the file at all. The game doesn't read the new data, and when I manually go and check the file it's still the same as before. I'm using my school's server to host the files so I'm not sure about how it's set up, but I was wondering if anyone had any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Tried your code. Works fine for me.

Comment: [**This answer on SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7895355/1415724) may help. Also check for file permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Use [is_writable](https://www.php.net/is_writable) before attempting to write the contents. If info.json is not writable than attempt to [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) the file permissions, then attempt the write again.

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('info.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString,true);
$data["doors"][0]["right"] = true;
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
var_dump($newJsonString);

$filename = 'info.json';

// Check if writable, if not chmod and set if successful
$writable = ( is_writable($filename) ) ? TRUE : chmod($filename, 0755);
if ( $writable ) {
    file_put_contents($filename, $newJsonString);
} else {
    // FAIL
}
```

Comment: That's failing for me as well

Comment: Change `// FAIL` to something that will give you some feedback so you know if the `file_put_contents` is failing or the `is_writable` and `chmod` functions are. If it's the later than you'll need to chmod the file via the command line (ssh) or via FTP (change permissions).

Answer (score 0):

If the is_writable test fails you lack the permissions necessary to write to the json file. This is probably becuase you are trying to write to is as a server process (e.g. var/www). Please refer to bottom post, (the exact same problem) and try the chmod *for testing purposes only*. It's best practice NOT to write to file I/O as server, try using PDO or mysqli.

[Update JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870672/update-json-file-with-php)