# Change permissions for each directory in a path using bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to change the permissions for each directory in a path that a user will specify. This will be completed in a bash script. For example:

```
DIR = /a/b/c/d/e/f/

chmod 777 /a/b/c/d/e/f/

chmod 777 /a/b/c/d/e/

chmod 777 /a/b/c/d/

chmod 777 /a/b/c/

chmod 777 /a/b/

chmod 777 /a/
```

**777 is only an example. Solution should allow for any permissions.**

I do not want to change permissions of files within the directories and I can not assume these are the only sub-directories. I only want to change the permissions that are explicitly in the path given by the user.

Comment: The question is explicitly different from that in that is wants to chmod a folder and all of it's _ancestors_ but none of the siblings of those ancestors.

Comment: Sounds like a simple loop (while `$f` do `chmod "$f"`, `f=$(basename "$f")`).

Comment: Whatever the provlem is that you are trying to solve, **`chmod 777` is almost certainly *wrong and dangerous***. You should revert to a sane permission which doesn't include write access for random strangers to system files.

Comment: Notice also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338641/in-a-php-apache-linux-context-why-exactly-is-chmod-777-dangerous and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment

Comment: @TobySpeight Can you explain how that would solve my question? How would f go from /base/next/ to /base/next/final/ ?

Comment: @jww I was unaware Bash scripting is not considered programming or development. There are other questions on this site regarding bash.

Comment: @tripleee I used 777 as an example. The permissions is insignificant because that can change with the correct solution.

Comment: @Jayson - Bash scripts are on-topic. Perhaps you can point out where the script is. This is malformed so I know you are not running the garbage from the question: *`DIR = /a/b/c/d/e/f/`*. The best I can tell, this is just another question about how to use a command that's already been asked and answered with *"... in a script"* tacked on.

Comment: @Jayson - the other way around - that takes you from `/a/b/c/d/e/f` to `/a/b/c/d/e`, then to `/a/b/c/d` etc.  (And obviously, I meant to write `dirname`, not `basename`).

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way is to start at the deepest point, and iterate upwards using `dirname` in a loop:

```
perms=a+rX
d=a/b/c/d/e/f

while [ "$d" != . ]
do
    chmod $perms "$d"
    d=$(dirname "$d")
done
```

This is all portable shell, so doesn't depend on Bash - any POSIX-compliant shell will suffice.

I've used relative directory names, as you really don't want to be changing permissions of `/` on a real system.

You could of course just use a substitution expansion instead of invoking
 `dirname` if you want: `d=${d%/*}`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you want to set 777 on some directories ?

Anyway, you can achieve this with `dirname` and recurse on `$DIR` until the root directory:

```
DIR=/a/b/c/d/e/f/
while [[ $DIR =~ /.+ ]] ;do
  chmod 777 $DIR
  DIR=$(dirname $DIR)
done
```

Comment: I like this solution. I see how it works after doing some research on =~ and dirname. 777 was an arbitrary permissions.